# how to display the congratulation view in iPhone using objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am developing a learning app for preschool kids. This is my code:

```
  numbersStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png",@"10.png", nil];
    commonFunctionObject = [[SpeechCommonFunctions alloc]init];
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    counter = 0;
    isMicPresent = YES;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatActionFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)repeatActionFire
{
    if(counter >= numbersStoreArray.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_numbersShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];
    }
    else
    {
        [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:numbersStoreArray :counter :_numbersShowImageView :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [commonFunctionObject recordPlayAction];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    counter+=1;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}

- (IBAction)retryButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}
```

After completion of this, this entry to the `repeatActionFire` and show finished. My question is: I need to display the congratulation view after the completion of the game and need to use two buttons.

Buttons for:

1. to reach the homepage
2. to retry the game.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried actionsheet controller ? U can subclass for custom view but think it should be able to give this option

Comment: You need to create another UIView and then you can add the background image to it and the two buttons. Then you show/hide this UIView as needed.

Comment: you should navigate to a controller that displays your congratulation message and the buttons you want. that will be easy for further navigation and you also present it with some animations.